# Excel Taskpane Addin looses cookies with Edge

Tags: excel, cookies, microsoft-edge, excel-addins, office365-apps

I had developed an Office Addin, with a Taskpane.

Without closing the current Excel document, showing repeatedly the Taskpane in an Excel Addin should preserve cookies.

If Excel uses **Edge** to host the Addin in the Taskpane, when the Taskpane is opened more than once, the cookies that were stored by the Addin just when it was opened the time before, are gone.

The issue is present only If Excel uses **Edge** to host the Addin in the Taskpane.
Instead, If Excel uses **IE** to host the Addin in the Taskpane, there is no issue.

This issue affects Addins that rely on cookies from 3rd party domains, acquired after authentication.

For example, in my case:
My Addin uses the OfficeDialog to authenticate to a 3rd party domain. After the OfficeDialog took me to the 3rd party authentication URL, some cookies for that domain are returned.
If i don't close or reload the Addin, the cookies are there, and the Addin can call some APIs in the 3rd party domain.
But if the Addin is reloaded, the 3rd party cookies are lost, and the user has to authenticate again.
This happens only with Edge, not with IE, in the Taskpane.

I don't know if this is a bug, but imo Edge should preserve cookies, exactly like IE does.

(The Taskpane could contain different browsers/versions as explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins)

*My Office version number: Office 365 ProPlus Version 1910 (Build 12130.20272 Click-to-Run)*

*My Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Version 1903 (OS Build 18362.467)*

Comment: Please check the Edge browser setting, make sure you are not blocking the cookies (Click **Setting and More** located on the top-right corner and select **Settings**.
Open the **Privacy & security** tab, Under **Cookies**, choose **Don't block cookies**). Besides, you could also check the Internet Properties, make sure it doesn't block the cookies, more detail steps, please check [this article](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/edge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-blocking-cookies-windows-10/3d865aca-a21e-445d-9804-d45a5d02efa2).

Comment: Thanks Zhi, i verified with Edge DevTools that cookies are created.
But when Taskpane is opened again (or closed and reopened) the cookies are gone, when Edge is used in the Taskpane. 
Instead if IE is used in the Taskpane, the cookies are still there, as expected.

Comment: can you post the detail steps and Enough code to reproduce the problem. It might be easier to help you solve the problem.

Comment: It's a bug. It is opened here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/846